# Error: Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, lint

I'm using VS Code and when I use `pygame.init()` this error appears:

```
Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member
```

I tried to add `--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame` to `python.linting.pylintArgs` in the settings and the error stopped, but then almost all of my code turns blue and says those errors:

```
Constant name "grid1" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming stylepylint(invalid-name)
```

**Edit**: So this is a linter warning, I would like to remove but when I tried using the method above, everything gets a blue line under it.

My OS is Windows 10 and I'm using the latest python version and latest pygame version.

Comment: The latter "error" is definitely only a linter warning which means that your code has "style errors". Ideally, you'll repair those, but your code should still run without that. Does it? You should add more detail to your question anyway. Just click on "edit" below the text.

Comment: Is "Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member" even an error or just a linter message, too?

Comment: What is your OS? Which version of python do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting bombarded by those errors as your probably code does not conform to the PEP8 style of writing Python code.

Right-click anywhere in your file and click `Format Document` or press `Alt+Shift+F` to format your code automatically. After that, just look at the remaining warnings and errors and try to fix them. The errors are probably just asking you to make docstring for functions and classes.

If you don't want to write docstrings, add this to your VSCode settings.json file

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0114, C0116",
],
```